# Calling x64 .asm file from C#?

Tags: c#, assembly

I've seen inline 32-bit .asm called from C++ Visual Studio 2010, called x64 hand-written .asm files from a C++ project using Microsoft's __fastcall protocol and the whole "extern C" header thing, but I don't see an equivalent in C#(my preferred language).

From a C# file, is there a way to call a hand-written 64-bit .asm file in a C# Winforms app?

Comment: basically yes - but you will need to use `unsafe` code to achieve that... why would you want to do that ?

Comment: What does the C++ declaration of the functions look like? You could probably pinvoke calls into that assembly.

Comment: It's basic graphics stuff(brightness, saturation, contrast) for giant (>500mb) bitmaps. Pinvoke is 32 bit if I understand correctly?

Comment: that stuff is not worth the trouble... implement whatever you need in C/C++ and call that DLL via `DLLImport` from C# - it will be fast enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you really need to execute assembly code from C# see for example [here](http://www.conic.se/blog/posts/12/) - using `unsafe` code, pointers, unamaged delegates and a byte array containing the assembler in binary form...

Comment: that's x86, is there no x64? (or x86-64)

Comment: That really likes to fail. The right way, if there is such a thing, it to VirtualAlloc some memory that is actually marked executable.

Comment: it works with both (32 bit and 64 bit) - it works with whatever processor architecure you are running ond as long as you use the right instruction set... it might fail in the future because of security measures so the `VirtualAlloc` route is "safer" although the whole thing is unsafe...

Comment: @harold that is very likely since DEP is meant to thwart such attempts... currently the most "right" option I see would be to build a DLL and call that...

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [This code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1392/Using-Unmanaged-code-and-assembler-in-C). It describes techniques for mixing assembly into c++ then calling the c++ assembly within C#.

Comment: Done that in C++ but using registers like RAX(64bit) instead of EAX(32bit). Doesn't it seem odd to write a C# file calling a C++ file for the sole purpose of calling a 64bit asm?

Comment: Honestly personally it seems odd to be using assembly, let alone most unmanaged code in c# so a hack is due to be unnecessary. If I needed to have assembly for optimization or whatnot I would have written those parts into a C++ DLL anyway

Comment: That's what I thought initially but i got a 3 to 6x speedup using x64 MASM over the C++ DLL. I guess optimizing compilers still don't get that really slick professional feel that basic Photoshop filters have.